# deleting a linked list node, C++ function not working

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class List {
public:
    struct node {
        int data;
        node *next;
    };
    node* head = NULL;
    node* tail = NULL;
    node* temp = NULL;
    node* prev = NULL;
public:
    void addNum(int num) {
        temp = new node;
        temp->data = num;
        temp->next = NULL;
        if (head == NULL) {
            head = temp;
            tail = temp;
        }
        else {
            tail->next = temp;
            tail = temp;
        }
    }
    void PrintList() {
        temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL) {
            cout << temp->data << endl;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    void DelNum(int num) {
        temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL) {
            if (temp->data == num) {
                prev->next = temp->next;
                free(temp);
            }
            temp = prev;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
};

int main() {

    List list;
    list.addNum(1);
    list.addNum(2);
    list.addNum(3);
    list.addNum(4);
    list.addNum(5);
    list.addNum(6);

    list.DelNum(3);
    list.PrintList();
    return 0;
}
```

What is wrong with my DelNum function? When I run the program nothing pops up. Doesn't matter what number I put in.

Comment: Did you try to debug `List::DelNum()` step-wise? 1.) Why is `temp` a member variable? You use it locally only. 2.) The same about `prev`. 3.) Please, focus on usage of `prev` in `List::DelNum()`. You use `prev` to remember predecessor of current node. 3.1) Whery do you assign it? (I couldn't find any assignment where `prev` is on left hand side.) 3.2) Did you consider the case where node in `head` has to be deleted? (Please, think about `prev` in this case as `head` has no predecessor.) 4.) You store two ends of list: `head` and `tail`. There are special cases for `head`. What about `tail`?

Comment: `temp` and `prev` should be local variables, not member variables. Not only makes it the code clearer, it also enables the compiler to better check the code and give you a warning that will tell you what you are doing wrong in `DelNum`. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two main problems are there in DelNum function:

first,  when you are in while loop
, you should assign

```
prev = temp;
```

second, when you have found your target element, after deleting it you have to break out of the loop, which isn't done in your code

below is your corrected code( also correction of some other corner case in DelNum function ):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class List {
public:
    struct node {
        int data;
        node *next;
    };
    node* head = NULL;
    node* tail = NULL;
    node* temp = NULL;
    node* prev = NULL;
public:
    void addNum(int num) {
        temp = new node;
        temp->data = num;
        temp->next = NULL;
        if (head == NULL) {
            head = temp;
            tail = temp;
        }
        else {
            tail->next = temp;
            tail = temp;
        }

      cout<<num<<" is added \n";
    }
    void PrintList() {
        temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL) {
            cout << temp->data << endl;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
        void DelNum(int num) {

        if(head==NULL)//empty
        {
            cout<<"empty linked list, can't be deleted\n";
            return;
        }
        if(head->next==NULL)//means only one element is left
        {
            if(head->data==num)
            {
                node * fordelete=head;
                head=NULL;
                cout<<num<<"is deleted\n";
                delete(fordelete);
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"not found , can't be deleted\n";
            }
            return;

        }
       temp = head;  // when more than one element are there
       prev = temp;
        while (temp != NULL) {

            if (temp->data == num) {
                prev->next = temp->next;
                free(temp);

            cout<<num<<" is deleted\n";
                break;

            }
            prev= temp;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        if(temp==NULL)
        {
            cout<<"not found, can't be deleted\n";
        }
    }
};

int main() {

    List list;
    list.addNum(1);
    list.addNum(2);
    list.addNum(3);
    list.addNum(4);
    list.addNum(5);
    list.addNum(6);

    list.PrintList();
    list.DelNum(3);
    list.DelNum(7);
    list.PrintList();
    return 0;
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

As mss pointed out the problem is in your DelNum() function where you assign `temp = prev;`. In your initialization you defined that `node* prev = NULL`; So, `prev = NULL` at the point when you assigned it to temp which caused segmentation fault when you try to use it like `temp = temp->next`;.